# Profile a gulp build with spy-js

Tags: node.js, webstorm

From one of the comment in the [webstorm blog](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/08/tracing-debugging-and-profiling-node-js-with-spy-js/) article, it says one can debug a grunt program by creating a script file and invoke with grunt. I have a `gulp` setup I like to profile. So, I created a script file with

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
require('./gulpfile');
gulp.start.apply(gulp, ['default'])
```

when I run this with a `spy-js` run session, it executes and ton of trace info. The `traced application` window shows it ran correctly as I could see the logs. But, I cannot find any of my methods in `trace run` window. Where should I look for say, a function called from my `gulpfile.js`? I tried quick search by clicking on middle window and start typing. But I cannot find any of my method.

Another qn, how to go to the next hit in the `quick search` window. As in the attached image, it hit one result, but I want to go to the next. How?[image]

Comment: As for your second question with the quick search: The Arrow-Up- and Down-Keys do all the magic ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way would be to use [capture exclusions](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/04/spy-js-webstorm-secret-service/#settings) to get rid of the noise from the files you're not interested in.

[image: capture exclusions]

On the screenshot above, single file filter is applied (meaning that nothing but this file will be captured), so after applying such filter and restarting the session you will only see the code from gulpfile.js. You can use glob patterns to include/exclude files you need. I suspect in your scenario excluding all node modules should be enough. There's a shortcut to create such filter, just right click on the root node inside the events pane and select "Mute node modules":

[image]

If you're interested in tracing some of the node modules, you can modify the filter to exclude just those you're not interested in. You can also create filters for individual node modules by locating one of their functions in the stack tree and using "Mute this node module" context action.